# 'cupy.core.core.ndarray' object has no attribute 'unique'

Tags: python, cupy, rapids

I was transforming categorical features using `factorize()` function which returns a tuple of a `cupy` array and strings. I assigned the `cupy` array into a variable named `codes`. However, I can't seem to get the unique values of `codes` using `codes.unique()`

It returns an error message:

> AttrubuteError: 'cupy.core.core.ndarray' object has no attribute 'unique'

```
# use factorize to create continuous integers from a categorical feature (returns a tuple)
codes, uniques = df_train['product_id'].factorize()
codes.unique()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-27db0fac06a1> in <module>()
----> 1 codes.unique()

AttributeError: 'cupy.core.core.ndarray' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb1eq.png)

Appreciate the help and suggestion to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to call `cupy.unique(codes)` instead of `codes.unique()` like you could if it were a regular NumPy array.  Docs: https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.unique.html

It was added in this PR: https://github.com/cupy/cupy/pull/1140 which as you may be able to see did not add it as a method on the array type.

Comment: Ahh I see, I was following a tutorial made last year. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answer solved your problem please "accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

CuPy is designed to be highly compatible with NumPy, and in this case note that `numpy.ndarray` does not have a `unique()` method either; for both NumPy and CuPy it lives under the main namespace as a regular function (`numpy.unique()`/`cupy.unique()`). So it is an invalid usage not specific to CuPy IMHO.